# stylish rocco documentation for API -like stripe.com- ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

While working on documenting a fairly large REST api and looking for good presentation particularly, I came across the stripe.com api documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api

I initially started with documenting API usage in a simple text file while I am doing progress on the project.But now that I will have other engineers working with me and users interacting with the API I would like to produce something like the stripe.com documentation.

I came across rocco, and it is pretty nice ! but I have no idea how stripe peeps formatted the right hand column to render bold titles, json payload and ....

Any examples?

I am pretty aware the API documentation is a fairly common questions, but I am asking about how to use rocco to similar to render more than just code on the right hand side column.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it with rocco, but in case you can change the builder you have [api_docs](https://github.com/twg/api_docs) gem which provides a nice bootstrap formatted output.

[image: api_doc output example]